# How to simplify this type of statement? If A is such that B if C then D.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, proof-explanation

A step function is integrable. In particular, if $x_0, x_1, ..., x_N$ is a partition of the interval $[a,b]$, if $c_1, c_2, ..., c_N\in \mathbb{R}$ and if $f:[a,b] \to \mathbb{R}$ is such that $f(x)=c_i$ if $x_{i-1} < x<x_i$ for $i=1,...,N$, then

$$\int_{a}^{b} f= \sum_{n=1}^{N} c_i(x_i-x_{i-1})$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could simplify it slightly by writing a step function as the sum of indicators:

Given a step function

$$ f= \sum\limits_{n=1}^{N} c_i  \ \mathbb{I}_{(x_{n-1},x_n)} $$

We define

$$ \int\limits_{a}^b f = \sum\limits_{n=1}^{N} c_i (x_n - x_{n-1})   $$

In this context, it is typically understood what is meant by the notation. If this is your first time seeing these things however, and you are asked to define something like this in an exam, I'd say stick with your more detailed definition.